# Displaying categories from database

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display categories for each post on an HTML table, and it's not giving any errors.

Well, the query is good. I didn't find any kind of misspelled variables.

[image: I get the post status in category side]

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM  posts";
$se_posts = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($se_posts)) {
    $post_id = $row['post_id']; 
    $post_author = $row['post_author']; 
    $post_title = $row['post_title']; 
    $post_category_id = $row['post_category_id']; 
    $post_status = $row['post_status']; 
    $post_image = $row['post_image']; 
    $post_tags = $row['post_tags']; 
    $post_comment_count = $row['post_comment_count']; 
    $post_date = $row['post_date']; 

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$post_id}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$post_author}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$post_title}</td>";

    // show post category
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id Like $post_category_id";
    $query_update_cat = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_update_cat)) {
        $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];  
        $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

        echo "<td>{$cat_title}</td>";
    }

    echo "<td>{$post_status}</td>";
    echo "<td><img class='img-responsive' width='100'src='../images/{$post_image}'></td>";
    echo "<td>{$post_tags}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$post_comment_count}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$post_date}</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='post.php?delete={$post_id}'>delete</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='post.php?source=edit_post&p_id={$post_id}'>Edit</a></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}  
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: did you check the image?

Comment: You have written 
echo "<td>{$post_status}</td>"; to display the status. Try removing it.

Comment: well i did now im getting the image in category field :\

Comment: What is your expected result? I helped you display the image inline in your question, btw, your 2nd query can be improved by merging with 1st query with a JOIN.

Comment: Your columns and the heading do not match. Match one by one, You will find the issue. In your case $post_status must be printing category.

Comment: it is matched $post_category_id did u see it?

Comment: you should not use like when you are quering for ID, please use "=" instead. also you are trying to send a request to get categories on every post, you should reduce number of requests also, @Alan check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem that you are making a request on every post (or article).
And this is wrong, you should reduce the number of requests as much as you can. Also, you are using LIKE !! you should use equal '='.

for your query:

at this inside the categories loop you should define $cat_title before the loop, then set it in the loop, and outside the loop print it :

```
$cat_title = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_update_cat)){
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];  
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
}
echo "<td>{$cat_title}</td>";
```

try with this query with JOIN:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM  posts JOIN categories ON (posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id)";

$se_posts= mysqli_query($connection,$query);
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>post id</td>
    <td>post author</td>
    <td>post title</td>
    <td>category</td>
    <td>post status</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>tags</td>
    <td>comment count</td>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>action</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($se_posts)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['post_id']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['post_author']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['post_title']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['cat_title']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['post_status']}</td>";
    echo "<td><img class='img-responsive' width='100'src=\"../images/{$row['post_image']}\"></td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['post_tags']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['post_comment_count}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['post_date']}</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"post.php?delete={$row['post_id']}\">delete</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"post.php?source=edit_post&p_id={$row['post_id']}\">Edit</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: well i tried to JOIN the 2 quereis based on @raptors advice but still no good :)

Comment: there is no posts showing when running your code just an empty table

Comment: @Alan, I edited the answer check it please. just change the categories loop inside..